# Multiple times input a file to a executable file

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I am working on a learning algorithm, and I am giving inputs from command line using input file, like following:-
   c:\user\document> SBP < input.txt

But I want to input this file multiple times(not definite) till training error is not below certain threshold, How can I do it..

Answer (score 2):

You can either give it multiple times on the command line, like

```
 ./command.exe input.txt input.txt input.txt
```

or give it once

```
 ./command.exe input.txt
```

and open it multiple times when you need it

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        std::ifstream f(argv[1]);
        // process input
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to re-design your SBP program to include the loop over the iterations of learning. This way you read the data input only once and then process it inside the program. Optionally you may consider supplying your program with the parameter input file (e.g. maximal number of iterations (how many times the data is presented to the learning algorithm), error threshold, some other parameters, even the name of the data file to read (so to skip supplying it from the command line)). So eventually you may come up to the input as:

```
c:\user\document> SBP < input_parameters.txt input_data.txt
```

or simply

```
c:\user\document> SBP < input_parameters.txt
```

Sticking to a more-or-less standard user interface is a good thing to do.